# WinAppDriver - Windows app is launch with additional login screen and I am unable to switch on the login screen

Tags: automated-tests, winappdriver, windows-application-driver

When I launch my windows application, it is launched with two different screens i.e. one is application and one is login window.

By default, it remains on the main application and I am unable to switch to the login window.

When I am trying to locate an element using Appium Desktop, it captures only the main application but unable to load/switch the login window too. So I am also facing locating elements.

It would be great if someone gives some idea about switching windows and locating elements.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Switching windows works the same like in Selenium, I will make this example in C#.

`driver.WindowHandles.Count` gives you the amount of windows of the application, so if you don't know what index your window has, you try to switch through all of them.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < driver.WindowHandles.Count; i++)
{
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[i]);
}
```

You can also get the page source with `driver.PageSource` of the current window if you don't find the element in the inspector.